# My post content displays rn in bteween lines?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Whenever there is a space in between the post it soows `rn`. This is how I read the insert data:

```
$content_of_post_original = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post_content']);
$content_of_post = stripslashes($content_of_post_original);
```

And then printed:

```
echo $show['post_content']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\r\n` means a new line. Your strip slashes is removing this and just echoing `rn` instead of a new line.

Check out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: `$content_of_post_original = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post_content']);
$content_of_post = stripslashes(nl2br($content_of_post_original));`

Comment: thanks !  also  using str_replace("rn","<br/>", $show['post_content']) worked for me after doing above .

Comment: This is an old post, but I would like to recommend against using `str_replace("rn","<br/>", $show['post_content'])`.  There are many words that have r and n together sequentially.  It is very likely to inadvertently insert a `<br />` in places which you would not want it.  For example, the words: learn, burn, yearn, earn, turn, fern, return, scorn, popcorn, forlorn... There are so many... just please don't. :D